# Vagrant Puppet Provisioning failure due declarative structure

Tags: webserver, virtualbox, xdebug, puppet, vagrant

As the title describes I am having an issue provisioning a box successfully. I am trying to install a development box (Apache, PHP and XDebug)

Everything works fine except for the point where I have to include the XDebug functionality, since it is not supplied in the original REPO I am installing it through the Example42/puppet-yum REPO manager.

In this part there is a mistake, since when I try to build the box from scratch I get the the error that package php-perl-xdebug is not available. This is because the repo's are not yet initialized. I have tried several ways to make sure that it would update the repo's before doing any other action. Referencing the classes by -> but this would yield in a looped block. Going through Google did not yield any practical results that would make sure that some commands are ran before others.

I believe it is possible to do this wit the "Required" command, but I could't find a way to use it. 
Side note: We're mostly using example42 modules for our building.

Thanks in advance:

The following is the default.pp manifest for the application service.

**default.pp**

```
Exec { path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ] }


class system-setup {
   service { "iptables":
        ensure => stopped,
    }
}

class php-setup{
    php::module { "pdo": }
    php::module { "gd": }
    # php::module { "fpm": }
    php::module { "mysql": }
    php::module { "soap": }
    # php::module { "zts": }
    # php::module { "pecl-apc": }

    php::module { "pecl-memcache": }
    php::module { "xml": }
    php::module{ "pecl-xdebug": }
}

class apache-vhost {
    apache::vhost { 'trunk.project.dev':
        docroot             => '/var/www/html/',
        port                => '80',
    }
}

class { 'yum':
  extrarepo => [ 'epel' ],
}


class { 'apache':   
    source => [ "puppet:///modules/apache/httpd.conf-project" , "puppet:///modules/apache/httpd.conf" ], 
}   

class { 'php' :
    source => ["/vagrant/files/php.ini", "puppet:///modules/php/php.ini"],
}



include php-setup
include apache-vhost
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this somewhere:

Class['yum'] -> Package <||>

This is using a resource collector to make sure Class yum is done before any package is installed.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work.. I have added the **Class['yum'] -> Package <||> right above the include * . And it would still install the packages anyway. I think it's because one of the other subclasses is doing the package managing? I have attached an output of the console: http://pastebin.com/yGRfUpsD

Comment: No, that resource collector transcends classes. 

Another way to do it is to put the yum-class in an earlier runstage. If you include stdlib, a 'setup' runstage should be available.

class {'yum': 
  extrarepo => [ 'epel' ],
  stage     => 'setup',
}

Comment: You could also make this more specific:
Yumrepo['epel'] -> Package <||>

Comment: Somehow, this is also not working, with these three options I guess there is an issue with the script itself.. All the modules are from example42.. Result:http://pastebin.com/V4mcV0Ct Maybe I should reslove to the manual packaging...

Comment: Eventually after a lot of trial an error I came to this option: **Yum::Managed_yumrepo <| |> -> Package <||>**

Comment: Ah, ok I'm not too familiar with Example42 modules, good to hear that you've solved it!